# The token storage contains no authentication token

Tags: symfony

I'm stack heeeere in security, help me please!! 
 I got this error 2 days ago and couldn't solve it : "The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL." My login in the index page, and the login and login_check are in the same function (indexAction).This is my security.yml file, my controller, and my entity "user" :

```
                # you can read more about security in the related section of the documentation
                # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
                security:
                    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password


                  encoders:
                        #Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
                        CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\user: bcrypt

                    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
                    role_hierarchy:
                        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
                        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

                    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
                    providers:
                        in_memory:
                            memory:
                                users:
                                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
                        database:
                            entity:
                                class: CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\user
                                property: username
                    # the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
                    # for specific sections of your app
                    firewalls:
                        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
                        dev:
                            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                            security: false


 admin_area:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        form_login:
           check_path: _default_index
           login_path: _default_index

                    access_control:
                        #- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
                        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
        <?php

        namespace CNAM\CMSBundle\Controller;

        use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
        use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
        use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
        use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
        use CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\user;
        use CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\userprof;
        use CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\profil;
        use CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\privilege;
        use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response;
        use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
        use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
        use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
        use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;


        class DefaultController extends Controller
        {
            /**
             * @Route("/")
             * @Template()
             */
            public function indexAction(Request $request)
            {
                $user = new user();
                $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
                    ->add('id', 'text',array('attr'=>array('name'=>'login_user','required'=>'required',
                        'maxlength'=>'255','placeholder'=>'Votre matricule','id'=>'login_user')))
                    ->add('password', 'password',array('attr'=>array('name'=>'login_password','required'=>'required',
                        'maxlength'=>'20','placeholder'=>'Mot de passe','id'=>'login_password')))
                    ->add('Connexion', 'submit',array('attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block rounded_btn','id'=>'login_btn',
                        'style'=>"width:8vw;height:5vh;padding:0px 0px; position:relative;left:5vmin;top:1vmin;font-size:2vmin;")))
                    ->getForm();
                $form->handleRequest($request);
                //$b_search=$this->get('session')->get('search');
                $id = $request->request->get('id');
                $session = $request->getSession();

                if ($form->isValid()) {
                    $data = $form->getData();
                    $repository = $this
                        ->getDoctrine()
                        ->getManager()
                        ->getRepository("CNAMCMSBundle:user");
                    $rep = $this
                        ->getDoctrine()
                        ->getManager()
                        ->getRepository("CNAMCMSBundle:userprof");
                    $search = $repository->find($data);
                    $p_search=$rep->find($data);
                    $helper = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
                   if (!$search) {
                       //throw $this->createNotFoundException('Utilisateur introuvable!');

                     }
                   else {
                        //$session=$this->get("session");
                        //$session->start();
                        // $session->set('search', $search);
                        $user->setEtat(1);
                        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                        $user=$em->merge($user);
                        $em->flush();

                        $id_prof=$p_search->getIdProfil();

                        switch ($id_prof)
                        {
                            case 1: return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cnam_cms_default_webmaster'),301);break;
                            case 2: $user->setRole("ROLE_ADMIN");$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();$user=$em->merge($user);
                                $em->flush();return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cnam_cms_default_admin'),301);break;
                            case 3: return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cnam_cms_default_sup_med'),301);break;
                            case 4: return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cnam_cms_default_med'),301);break;
                            case 5: return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cnam_cms_default_gest_mp'),301);break;
                        }
                    }

                    //return $this->render('CNAMCMSBundle:Default:profile.html.twig', array(
                    //'search' => $search,
                    //'b_search'=>$b_search
                    // ));
                }
                return array('form'=>$form->createView());
               }
                /**
                 * @Route("/admin")
                 * @Template()
                 */
                public function adminAction()
               {
                   return $this->render('CNAMCMSBundle:Default:admin.html.twig', array());
               }

                /**
                 * @Route("/admin/gestEtat",name="gestEtat")
                 * @Template()
                 */
                public function gestEtatAction()
               {
                   return $this->render('CNAMCMSBundle:Default:gestEtat.html.twig', array());
               }

        }

    <?php

    namespace CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

    /**
     * user
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="user")
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class user implements UserInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *@Assert\NotBlank()
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *@Assert\NotBlank()
         * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=40)
         */
        private $password;

        /*
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="profil" , inversedBy="users")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_profil", referencedColumnName="id_profil")
         */
        private $profil;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->profil = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * @var boolean
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="etat", type="boolean")
         */
        private $etat;


        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
        /**
         * Set id
         *
         * @param integer $id
         * @return user
         */
        public function setId($id)
        {
            $this->id = $id;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Set password
         *
         * @param string $password
         * @return user
         */
        public function setPassword($password)
        {
            $this->password = $password;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get password
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getPassword()
        {
            return $this->password;
        }

        /**
         * Set etat
         *
         * @param boolean $etat
         * @return user
         */
        public function setEtat($etat)
        {
            $this->etat = $etat;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get etat
         *
         * @return boolean 
         */
        public function getEtat()
        {
            return $this->etat;
        }

        /**
         * Get profil
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        public function getProfil()
        {
            return $this->profil;
        }


        /**
         * Add profil
         *
         * @param \CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\user $profil
         * @return user
         */
        public function addProfil(\CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\profil $profil)
        {
            $this->profil[] = $profil;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove profil
         *
         * @param \CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\profil $profil
         */
        public function removeProfil(\CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\profil $profil)
        {
            $this->profil->removeElement($profil);
        }
        public function getUsername()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
        public function getRoles()
        {
            return array('ROLE_USER');
        }

        public function getSalt()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public function eraseCredentials()
        {

        }

        public function equals(UserInterface $user)
        {
            return $user->getId() == $this->getId();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You access control rules look weird as the first rule will always match and the one checking for the `ROLE_ADMIN` role will never match. You will want to reverse their order. To come back to your problem: Can you please show the full log for such a failing request?

Comment: please how can i make just the person who has the ADMIN_ROLE access to /admin page????  the index page("/") doesnt require any role, so the user can access to it anonymously.

Comment: I updated the question and posted my controller and my 'user' entity code.

Comment: Your access control rules will still not allow that as I wrote before. Your first rule catches all requests meaning that the second one will never be taken into account. You need to change their order.

Comment: so how to solve it? i know my problem but in that regex i putted what i need: i want the route "/"  which is the index page to be accessed by every one

Comment: Why don't you change the order of the access control rules then?

Comment: I got this error now "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."!!!!

Comment: Please update your question so that it matches your current environment and show the full debug log of such a failing request.

Comment: now m getting an other bug, so its not matter of security. I wanna debug my application, then test the security, if its still there a problem of security I will post it again.

Comment: The admin still not authenticated even after changing the access controll and the firewall!!